# Adding custom error messages for validation in Spring-MVC

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I am using Spring-MVC and I would like to do validation tests in backend. Currently I am able to perform the tests, redirect properly to the link. But I am only unable to add custom error messages incase there is a problem, Example : "Firstname is empty". I tried using the ValidationMessages_en_EN.properties file in WEB-INF, but that also didn't help. I am posting my code, kindly let me know where I am going wrong :

COntroller :

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        if(!(person==null)){
            return "redirect:/canvas/list";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
         //   model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
            model.addAttribute("notices",new Notes());
            model.addAttribute("canvases",new Canvas());
            return "person";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@Valid Person person,BindingResult bindingResult,@ModelAttribute("person") Person p,Model model){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "redirect:/";
        }
            this.personService.addPerson(p);
            return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
    private int id;

    @Valid
    @NotEmpty @Email(message = "username.empty")
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;


    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;


    @Valid
    @Size(min = 2,max = 30,message = "firstName.empty")
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Valid
    @Size(min = 2,max = 50)
    @Column(name = "secretquestion")
    private String secretquestion;

    @Valid
    @Size(min = 2,max = 500,message = "secretanswer.empty")
    @Column(name = "secretanswer")
    private String secretanswer;
```

Servlet-Context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="ValidatorMessages_en_EN.properties"/>
           </beans:bean>
```

JSP/HTML :

```
      <c:url var="addAction" value="/person/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person" method="post">
<table>
    <c:if test="${!empty person.username}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="id">
                <spring:message text="ID"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
            <form:hidden path="id" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    </c:if>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="firstName">
                <spring:message text="FirstName"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="firstName" />
        </td>
        <td><form:errors path="firstName"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="username">
                <spring:message text="Email"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="username" />
        </td>
        <td><form:errors path="username"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="password">
                <spring:message text="Password"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="password" />
        </td>
        <td><form:errors path="Password"/>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="secretquestion">
            <spring:message text="secretquestion"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="secretquestion" />
    </td>
        <td><form:errors path="secretquestion"/>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="secretanswer">
                <spring:message text="secretanswer"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="secretanswer" />
        </td>
        <td><form:errors path="secretanswer"/>
    </tr>
```

POM.xml :

```
 <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Messages.properties :

```
firstName=firstName
Email=Email
Password=password
secretquestion=secretquestion
secretanswer=secretanswer
NotEmpty.person.firstName=firstName is required!
NotEmpty.person.username=Email is required!
NotEmpty.person.password=Password is required!
NotEmpty.person.secretquestion=SecretQuestion is required!
NotEmpty.person.secretanswer=SecretAnswer is required!
```

Messages_en_US.properties

```
firstName=firstName
Email=Email
Password=password
secretquestion=secretquestion
secretanswer=secretanswer
NotEmpty.person.firstName=firstName is required!
NotEmpty.person.username=Email is required!
NotEmpty.person.password=Password is required!
NotEmpty.person.secretquestion=SecretQuestion is required!
NotEmpty.person.secretanswer=SecretAnswer is required!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<spring:message text="FirstName"/>` Should be like `<spring:message code="FirstName"/>` try to replace **text to code** in your `<spring:message />` tag

and   change basename value to **ValidatorMessages** and  `en_US` Spring will append for you

```
 <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
         <beans:property name="basename" value="ValidatorMessages"/>
 </beans:bean>
```

sava your file as `ValidatorMessages_en_US.properties` in your `resource` folder

Comment: Hi Pravin, can you please check the error log which I have updated in main post for the problem.

Comment: Did that, I can now see in IDE that it can find the files. But still I am getting those error. Currently, in my resources folder has 2 files, messages.properties, messages_en_US.properties. Servlet property value="messages". Still, no luck.

Comment: Any idea man...I can see like the ResourceBundle and compare different languages in file. But it still gives me same error

Comment: In your resource folder file `ValidatorMessages_en_US.properties` must be present  as you put in `<beans:property name="basename" value="ValidatorMessages"/> `

Comment: Hi Pravin, Finally I changed the location of the files and got it working, but it still doesnt show me the error messages. Like when the user inputs wrong username, he should see that username not valid or something.

Comment: No if you keep it not valid emailId or empty  then that message will populate on your screen for username as @NotEmpty @Email(message = "Email not formatted correctly")

 are you getting any error now ??if yes please share it

Comment: I am not seeing any error. Can you check the updated post, I have updated the entity code and messages.properties for you. Thank you very much for all your help man.

Comment: update this in your code `<beans:property name="basename" value="Messages"/>`

Comment: I already have, I can see the form, which means it is able to take those values, but it cannot take the errors from there or what, I have no idea right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65222/discussion-between-akshay-and-pravin).

Answer (score 2):

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody 
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Response handleException(Exception e) {          
    Response response = new Response();
    if(e instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException ){
        MethodArgumentNotValidException methodException = (MethodArgumentNotValidException)e;
        BindingResult bindingResult =methodException.getBindingResult();
        if(bindingResult!=null && bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            List<FieldError> fieldErrorList= bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
            for(FieldError fieldError: fieldErrorList ){                    
                response.adderror(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            }
        }
    }       
    return response;
}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer and not just dump code.

Comment: From which package does `Response` come from?

Comment: This is a good answer, but for some intelligible explanation (e.g. where to put this method) see e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring#controlleradvice

Comment: @Benny: Response seems to be a custom clase here. You want to put something like `ResponseEntity<YourResponseBody>`  . generating the Response Entity explicitly, you can also omit the `@ResponseBody` and `@ResponseStatus`.