# How to retrieve the error message of an ErrorField in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I'm building a custom validator that relies on the `@Annotations` in my model/POJO (I can't use `@Valid` or extend `Validator`).

I correctly created and filled a `FieldError`. Now, my question is: how can I get the error message (from the file properties) that I have to display on the screen. I need to manipulate that message in a class, so I have to reach it before it is display on the screen with

For example, I know that one of the code of my FieldError is `Size.objectName.fieldName`. I need to get from the file properties the related message.

If I add my `FieldError` to `BindingResult`, `BindingResult` do all the work and turn "Size.objectName.fieldName" in "size should be between 3 and 10". 
How can I do it on my own?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Display all errors:

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="Form">
    <c:forEach var="error" items="${errors.allErrors}">
        <b><spring:message message="${error}" /></b>
        <br />
    </c:forEach>
    </spring:hasBindErrors>
```

Comment: Thank you man,  but my question was another one. My problem is not to display the error on a jsp page, but manipulate the error message,before it's displaied on the screen

Comment: sorry. for that you need a Bean  ResourceBundleMessageSource in your java config. a messages.properties in the resources folder and inside the custom text like "typeMismatch=Invalid format". perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017029/adding-custom-error-messages-for-validation-in-spring-mvc